# Debugging connection leak in postgres database in RDS

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Trying to debug a connection leak in postgres database instance in RDS

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Running the above query shows around 500 sessions, but all of them have `wait_event_type` ***Client*** and `wait_event` ***ClientRead***. Also all of them have `state` as ***Idle***. Are these sessions problematic or benign?
Btw when I ran the query there was no issues of connections not available. May be I need to run this query when experiencing connection issues. But wanted to make sure whatever I am see now points towards any issues.